# Unable to boot ubuntu after update

Tags: boot

I have updated ubuntu 11.10 to 3.0.0.17 generic and after updating ubuntu didn't boot. Why would that occur? How to recover ubuntu if it doesn't boot. It worked in recovery mode but couldn't load gui.help me please!!

Answer (score 1):

The first steep to recover from boot failure condition is to repair Grub and be sure it's working.

Boot from Live CD, when GUI start open a terminal an type this commands:

```
sudo -s -H
fdisk -l
```

loof for the boot partition (whit * simbol)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount –bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

replace sda1 for yout partition

```
chroot /mnt

grub-install –recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
```

(sda its the disk, don't use sda1 this is a partition)
my reference for this, I hope this to be useful.
http://www.luisarmandomedina.com/318/como-reparar-el-grub-en-ubuntu-10-04-lts/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on Ubuntu, and the problem really was in NVIDIA drivers. Possible solution I have posted in here ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/117000/ubuntu-cannot-boot-after-kernel-update-to-3-0-0-17-generic/117354#comment139194_117354 ), it helped me and I hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem personally on my laptop and it traced back to a custom NVIDIA driver that I had compiled into the kernel.  If you have any such drivers they may be preventing you from booting.

What fixed mine was going into recovery mode, remounting as read/write, and then recompiling the NVIDIA driver into the new kernel.  Then everything ran just like before.

Good luck!